# Android studio : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an android app on android studio, when i run the app directly from android studio it works fine, but when i generate apk to send it to any device and install it the app crashes and gives me this exception

```
RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.projects.epic.khosomaty.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.projects.epic.khosomaty.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.projects.epic.khosomaty-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

here is the class that cause the exception

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
        ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
    }
}
```

and here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.projects.epic.khosomaty">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.projects.epic.khosomaty.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="A............o" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/white" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Login"
            android:label="@string/log_in_tittle"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SignUp"
            android:label="@string/sign_up_tittle" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ChangePassword"
            android:label="@string/customer_change_password_tittle" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_merchant_details" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.GeneralSearchResult"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.DisscountsFilter"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.DiscountsFilterResult"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SaleDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sale_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantsFilter"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantsFilterResult"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <service android:name=".SendTokenIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FireBaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RegisterVerify"
            android:label="@string/customer_register_verify_tittle" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerHome"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerAddNumber"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerEditProfile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.projects.epic.khosomaty.Activities.CustomerHome" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MerchantLogin" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MerchantSignUp" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantHome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Activities.MerchantHome" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MerchantAddDiscount" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MerchantAddWallet" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantRecievedRequests"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Activities.MerchantRecievedRequests" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.WalletDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wallet_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RequestConfirmDetails"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantAddPurchase"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerTransaction"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.CustomerHome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Activities.CustomerTransaction" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MerchantRebatePoints"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerRebateConfirmation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Activities.CustomerRebateConfirmation" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerWallet"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_wallet" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.CustomerFavoriteMerchants" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerWalletTransactionDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_wallet_transaction_details" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.CustomerWalletDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_wallet_details" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Intro"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

does any one know why the app crashes when i generate apk ???

note that i changed package name before.

Comment: check your package name in build.gradle file with applicationId tag

Comment: applicationId "com.projects.epic.khosomaty"

Comment: can you please add your build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Badr please go with below Step and Link and just UNCHECK the instant run then Clean , Rebuild and Run project after this create your APK file..

```
To disable Instant Run:
```

Go to Android Studio

1- Open the File > Settings or Preferences dialog .

2- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

3- Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

please follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure you not overriding the manifest.xml with a new package name from build.gradle's **applicationId** field.

Also, if may I recommend something:

`public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }`

I don't think this is a good idea at all. Don't store a static instance of the application class. I would like to recommend to use activity.getApplication() any pass that as a reference!

Comment: ( applicationId "com.projects.epic.khosomaty"  ) this is from build.gradle file and package name is the same as in manifest

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException happened in my android studio project in two classes – in both of them there was lambda expressions. After I replaced lambda with anonymous class – the build was successful.